# How can I count in tuples?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, haskell-platform

I'm trying to return a list of the fans who give the same score for all the movies

so my list is for example: [("fan1", "f1", 3), ("fan1", "f2", 3), ("fan2", "f1", 5)]

and this should return ["fan1", "fan2"] because fan1 rated 2 films the same and also fan2 because its the only film it rated

so far I came up with the following code:

```
f :: [Film] -> [Fan]
f = nub . map (\(f, _, _) -> f) . filter (\(_, _, s) -> s == 5)
```

but this only gives me the fans who rated a movie 5 stars and I don't know what to do from here. I am trying use Sets and Maps

Comment: Why would the result not include `"fan2"`, who rated 'all' films `5`?

Comment: oh yes my bad thank you so much im going to edit it

Answer (score 1):

First, your type `Film` has a bad name if the fields are a fan-identifier and rating. A better name would be `FilmRating`.

But that isn't anyway a good type to solve you task, because you're thinking in terms of *what fan* has done XYZ. So the structure should actually rather be something like

```
[(Fan, (FilmName, Grade))]
```

or even

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

M.Map Fan (M.Map FilmName Grade)
```

To get there, you can first use a combination of `sortBy` and `groupBy` to gather all the gradings by the same fan into a list each, like

```
[ [("fan1", "f1", 3), ("fan1", "f2", 3)]
, [("fan2", "f1", 5)]
]
```

This can be simplified further by mapping a function that removes the redundant information of the fan names:

```
map (\l@((fanName,_,_):_) -> (fanName, map (\(_, filmName, grade) -> (filmName, grade)) l))
```

to get

```
[ ("fan1", [("f1", 3), ("f2", 3)]
, ("fan2", [("f1", 5)]
]
```

Over this list of lists, you can then use `filter` to get the fans that fulfill the property you're interested in. That requires a predicate

```
allRatingsSame :: [(a, Grade)] -> Bool
```

This can be done by a similar pattern matching,

```
allRatingsSame l@((_,g0):_) = all (___) l
```

With that you can then use

```
filter (\(_, ratings) -> allRatingsSame ratings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Maybe

f = Map.keys . Map.filter isJust . Map.fromListWith go . map (\(x,_,y) -> (x,Just y))
  where go (Just x) (Just y) | x == y = Just x
        go _ _ = Nothing
```

First, we transform the list by throwing away the film name we don't need, and also wrap each rating in `Just` for a later step. This results in a list like `[("fan1", Just 3), ("fan1", Just 3), ("fan2", Just 5)]`. Next, we turn this list of pairs into a map, combining duplicates with the `go` function. This results in a map where the value is `Just x` where `x` is the single rating the fan gave to every film, or `Nothing` if the fan gave different ratings to different films. Finally, we return the keys of all elements whose values are `Just` something.